# How to create Store for native binary format(.ID, .DAT, .Tab, .MAP) in geoserver

Tags: dictionary, gis, geoserver, mapserver

Hi i have four different file format (`.ID, .DAT, .Tab, .MAP`)  i have to upload these in `geoserver` and see the map . Are these file format supported by `geoserver.if` yes please help me how to do it i had done googled and haven't  found any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is a good question As far i know these file formates are not supported by the geoserver so if you want to see map i will suggest you should go for .shp file format